# Change all images coordinates [Windows Store App, C#/XAML]

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have many images and multiple pages on my project. i want my project to support multi screen resolution.
i've tried viewbox and i couldn't succeed so i tried this for one images

```
private void setResolution()
    {
        var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
        ratioHeight = bounds.Height / standartHeight;
        ratioWidth = bounds.Width / standartWidth;

        Canvas.SetLeft(img1, Canvas.GetLeft(img1) * (ratioWidth));
        Canvas.SetTop(img1, Canvas.GetTop(img1) * (ratioHeight));
        img1.Width = img1.ActualWidth * (ratioWidth);
        img1.Height = img1.ActualHeight * (ratioHeight);
    }
```

It worked but its too long and hard to apply this on about 500 pics.

Is there any way to get all images on stages and change their coordinates at once

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Possible solution if you add to your images the ratio. E.g. myimage.scale.140.png .This image will grater than the default myimage.scale.100.png. Try it maybe save you life. :D

Comment: thanks for reply, tried but .scale-100 only change image not coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
foreach (Image Images in FindVisualChildren<Image>(pageMain))
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(Images, Canvas.GetLeft(Images) * (ratioWidth));
            Canvas.SetTop(Images, Canvas.GetTop(Images) * (ratioHeight));
            Images.Width = Images.ActualWidth * (ratioWidth);
            Images.Height = Images.ActualHeight * (ratioHeight);
        }
```

it worked for me(pageMain is Page's name)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution (recommended by Microsoft) is to use a grid for placement, and to use multiple images to cope with multiple resolutions. Their solution will provide dynamic placement of elements and load the correct image.

Have a look at their page for [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

(there too much to it to paste the code here).

Comment: thanks for comment Paul. i cant change design. there are 500 images, i must do that dynamically.